# Upper character next to a separator

Tags: java, string, replace, uppercase

I'm looking for a shortest/quick way to upper a character next to a separator and lower all other.

Separator can be: `.`, `-`,

Example 1:

```
In: test.test-test test

Out: Test.Test-Test Test
```

Example 2:

```
In: TEST.TEST

Out: Test.Test
```

I have a long method doing it for now, but think it can be in one line with a good use of `replace();`

Comment: Why does the first word in your examples get an uppercase T? Looks like you haven't explained all the requirements.

Comment: In case you wondered why your question is being downvoted - you have shown no research effort and no attempt of solving the problem of your own. Please provide the code that you have and explain what is the problem with this code.

Comment: I have edited my answer and added another solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regex, capture character groups and call `toUpperCase()` and `toLowerCase()` on them:

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([a-z])([^. -]*)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    m.appendReplacement(sb, m.group(1).toUpperCase() + m.group(2).toLowerCase());
}
System.out.println(m.appendTail(sb).toString());
```

**EDIT:**

Another solution using `StringBuilder` (which is not synchronised and hence faster than `StringBuffer`), which removes the usage of `Matcher#appendReplacement(StringBuffer)` and `Matcher#appendTail(StringBuffer)` at the expense of a bit more complex regex:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z])(.*?)([. -]+|$)").matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    sb.append(m.group(1).toUpperCase());
    sb.append(m.group(2).toLowerCase());
    sb.append(m.group(3));
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Note there are three capture groups instead of two (we need to capture separator characters too because this doesn't do replacements as the `StringBuffer` version above):

1. `[a-zA-Z]` takes a single character that will be converted to upper case
2. `.*?` takes anything, but is "reluctant" rather than "greedy" - i.e. it takes as little as necessary (read [more about quantifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html))
3. `[. -]+|$` takes a sequence of separator characters or the end of string character

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer as it was replaced by StringBuilder in 2004.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Replaced? Then it would be deprecated. The only difference between these two is that `StringBuffer` is synchronised and `StringBuilder` is not. And in this snippet of code `appendReplacement()` and `appendTail()` methods require `StringBuffer` so changing it is not just a matter of changing `sb` declaration.

Comment: You make a good point about those methods. The Javadoc for StringBuffer states " As of release JDK 5, this class has been supplemented with an equivalent class designed for use by a single thread, {@link StringBuilder}. The StringBuilder class should generally be used in preference to this one, as it supports all of the same operations but it is faster, as it performs no synchronization."

Comment: It is generally very hard to use StringBuffer correctly with multiple threads without additional locking, however if you have an API which requires it, as you do, it is needed.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I've done `StringBuilder` solution :) I think it might be considered easier, as it requires comparable knowledge of regex, but doesn't require knowledge of these two `Matcher` methods

Answer (score 0):

You could use **WordUtils** library from Apache. They've this method   [capitalizeFully(String str, char[] delimiters)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/lang/WordUtils.html#capitalizeFully(java.lang.String,%20char[])) which you can use in your scenario. Here is the description of that method:

> Converts all the delimiter separated words in a String into capitalized words, that is each word is made up of a titlecase character and then a series of lowercase characters.

You can use this method as follows:

```
WordUtils.capitalizeFully("test.test-test test", {' ', '.', '-'})
```

Return value:

```
Test.Test-Test Test
```